# How can I implement OnClickListener of an ImageView in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

> Can anyone kindly help me implement the opening of a new activity upon clicking of an ImageView. I have a code snippet displayed below.

```
public class TabFan extends Fragment {

//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fan, container, false);

    // Onclick Listening
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(this);


}
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Launching new Activity on hitting the image
    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
    startActivity(j);
    // End intent
}
```

}

> Ok I have a code with three tabs, the following controls my tabs which is working right.

```
public class Fans extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

//This is our tablayout
private TabLayout tabLayout;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fans);

    //Adding toolbar to the activity
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Fans"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Jersey"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Team"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

}

> I have another class pager

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

//integer to count number of tabs
int tabCount;

//Constructor to the class
public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
    super(fm);
    //Initializing tab count
    this.tabCount= tabCount;
}

//Overriding method getItem
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //Returning the current tabs
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFan tab1 = new TabFan();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabJersey tab2 = new TabJersey();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabTeam tab3 = new TabTeam();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

//Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
```

}

> Finally the interested raw class TabFan, now where exactly should that listener be implemented. I have tried the class Fans but apparently am getting some crush, TabFan seem not to work with the events too. Any help please.

```
public class TabFan extends Fragment {

//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fan, container, false);

    // Onclick Listener
}
```

}

Comment: java 101: you can't have code after a `return` statement. You need to find the image from the view you inflated, before returning it

Comment: @njzk2 this is the correct way, you are so attentive. +1

Comment: @njzk2 I have just edited the question; kindly advice on the right position I can set up the event listener. I think I may be putting the code in the wrong section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code that you have provided, you will need to do two things to properly link the `image` object to the `onClick()` method that you have written.

First, the Fragment class needs to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface. This is what makes the `onClick(View v)`actually activate on a click when using `setOnClickListener(this)`. Replace your class declaration line with:

```
public class TabFan extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Second, if you are going to add any more clickable objects to `TabFan` with `setOnClickListener(this)`, then `onClick(View v)` needs to verify that it is dealing with the expected View:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.image) {
        // Launching new Activity on hitting the image
        Intent j = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
        startActivity(j);
        // End intent
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just placed your code but seemingly there are some incompatibility issues. Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext() in fragment. Any way forward or fixing tricks...

Comment: Yes, as edited above, within a Fragment you must get the activity reference first and obtain the application context from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keys, `Android Studio` will show you suggestion window and generate overriding methods like `onClick` for you.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent j = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
```

Doesn't matter where you are, in `Fragment` or in `Activity`. `ImageView` just needs `View.OnClickListener`. for detecting click events override `onClick` method.

And another point when you need any `context` in fragment use `getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: that's not entirely the issue, here

Comment: @njzk2 i think you are right. Just want to guide him.

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is setting up the onClick in the XML already like this:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="yourMethod"
        android:src="@drawable/yourpicture"/>
```

Then in your Fragment or Activity just implement yourMethod to open the new Activity:

```
public void yourMethod(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ToOpenAcitivy.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also  [this site](https://guides.codepath.com/android) helped me a lot when learning about stuff like this.